# con:settings Elements in Workspace and Project Files

Tags: configuration, soapui

I am using the free edition of SoapUI (version 4.6.1) with multiple workspaces.  One of my frustrations is that SoapUI does not seem to support workspace-level custom properties.

The `*-soapui-workspace.xml` files I have reviewed contain an empty `con:settings` element (i.e. `<con:settings/>`).  Same in the `*-soapui-project.xml` files I have reviewed.

My intuition & hope is that these elements allow workspace- or project-level additions to or overrides of settings I see in my general `soapui-settings.xml` file - e.g. additional global properties that I want when a given workspace is loaded.

However, when I create a settings file `SomeService Tests-soapui-settings.xml` that contains...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-settings xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
<con:setting id="GlobalPropertySettings@properties"><![CDATA[<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
  <con:property>
    <con:name>WorkspaceCustomPropertyTest</con:name>
    <con:value>some value</con:value>
  </con:property>
</xml-fragment>]]>
</con:setting>
</con:soapui-settings>
```

...and set the `con:settings` element in the `SomeService Tests-soapui-workspace.xml` file like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:soapui-workspace name="SomeService Tests" soapui-version="4.6.1" projectRoot="${workspaceDir}" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
  <con:description>Workspace to organize all SomeService test projects.</con:description>
  <con:settings>SomeService Tests-soapui-settings.xml</con:settings> <!-- Reference the workspace settings file. -->
  <con:project name="SomeService Authentication Tests">SomeService Authentication Tests-soapui-project.xml</con:project>
</con:soapui-workspace>
```

..., nothing happens.

I do not get an error upon loading the workspace, but I also do not get any indication that the `con:settings` element is doing anything either.  For example, SoapUI Preferences > Global Properties does not list a `WorkspaceCustomPropertyTest` property.

I can keep tinkering of course, but an explanation of the workspace- and project-file `con:settings` elements would help.

Searching SO, the [SmartBear SoapUI forum](http://forum.soapui.org/), and more broadly for an explanation of the workspace- and project-file `con:settings` elements has yielded nothing so far.

*Can anyone explain how to use the workspace- and project-file `con:settings` elements?*

*Alternatively, can anyone shed light on how to achieve a similar result (i.e. workspace-level custom properties) with the free edition of SoapUI?*

Comment: What kind of data do you have in your workspace level setting file? Can you not create a properties file and read it using groovy? A separate file for each workspace?

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana: Just basic name-value pairs - e.g. `ServiceHost=server01.some.domain`, `ServiceDirectory=/vdir1/vdir2/` etcetera - that I would otherwise need to repeat across projects.  Reading them from workspace-properties file into a [poor man's script library](http://www.doan.me/script-library-in-soapui-free.aspx) in each project is a potential workaround I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that?

Create a ini("myconfig.groovy") file("assuming that this file will be in the same directory of your project file"):

```
global_property='Global value'
```

Use this groovy script to grab the property:

```
// Script imports
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils
import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper

// Grovvy utils handle OS directories path abstraction
def groovyUtils = new GroovyUtils(context)

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(groovyUtils.projectPath + '/myconfig.groovy').toURL())

// Just logging the property but you can set the property here
log.info config.global_property
```

Then you can add the value to the desired object at run time.

Comment: This works to add properties to `config` _within the scope of a project Load Script_ - where I added the code.  What really want is to reference `config`'s properties _project-wide_ - e.g. a Groovy Script test step.  Giving that a whirl, I got the error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script1`.  Adding the slurped properties to `config` defined in a [poor man's script library](http://www.doan.me/script-library-in-soapui-free.aspx) within the project like I've read about might be way to reference them project-wide I guess.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think you can add this to the project load script. Use project.setPropertyValue('global_property', config.global_property) to set the property. This will be available to all test suits and cases. Another option is set a environment in your system and use something like this: ${#System#my_variable}. But my option is use the set script on the test suite I never used project scripts.

Comment: I added it to a project Load Script already as a PoC; but you make a fair point about just setting a custom project property for each workspace-level property it slurps for project-wide access.  Duh! :P  With decent explanation of using a workspace-level properties file and related Groovy in each workspace project, I may not know how to leverage the `con:settings` elements about which I asked...but see that it hardly matters - setting aside concerns about minimizing & maintaining common project code and handling potential project custom-properties clutter (i.e. issues I can work out).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem possible to do it at the workspace level. You could do it at one of the testing levels, see: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html

Comment: Thanks.  I am aware of the ability to define properties at other levels in SoapUI.  It's workspace level properties - or the equivalent thereof - that I want.

Answer (score -1):

SoapUI does support global properties.

In File> Preferences> Global Properties

Here you can assign Global Properties that spans all projects. Sadly, currently, it will be used for all work spaces. Hope this helps, having a groovy script to manually handle everything just seems a bit over kill to me.